# Removing multiple objects from a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I've created a HashMap facts, which holds key(className) and value(pojo).

I want to remove more than one class objects from that hashMap while sending it to a method, the code I've below only removes one Class object (response), what if I wanted to remove more then one, (say response & HULC). Also I don't want to remove the objects from **facts hashMap**, hence created another copy of it.

I would appreciate your inputs thanks in advance :)

```
public class TempAvengersTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TempAvengersTest test = new TempAvengersTest();

        //setting avengersVo
        AvengersVo avengersVo = new AvengersVo();
        avengersVo.setNumberOfSuperHeros("6");
        avengersVo.setReleaseDate("May6,2016");

        HulcVO hulcVo = new HulcVo();
        hulcVo.setweight("2000");
        hulcVo.setAggression("Max");

        IronManVo imVo = new IronManVo();
        imVo.setAttitude("Max");
        imVo.setNewGear(true);

        HashMap<String, Integer> positiveFeedback = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        positiveFeedback.put("IMDB", 8);
        positiveFeedback.put("rottenTomatoes", 78);

        AudienceResponseVo responseVo = new AudienceResponseVo();
        responseVo.setNegativeFeedbackInd(true);
        responseVo.setPositiveFeedback(positiveFeedback);

        HashMap<String, Object> facts = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        facts.put("Movie", avengersVo);
        facts.put("HULC", hulcVo);
        facts.put("IronMan", imVo);
        facts.put("response", responseVo);

        sendToPostScreeningHandler(test.sendToPreScreeningHandler(facts));


        System.out.println("\n\n********************************************  END  ********************************************");
    }

    private HashMap<String, Object> sendToPreScreeningHandler (HashMap<String, Object> facts){

        //" facts needs to be unchanged, Hence creating tmpFacts " !!!
        HashMap<String, Object> tmpFacts = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        tmpFacts.putAll(facts);

        //Deleting response object map from tmpFacts.
           for (Object key : facts.keySet()) {
                if("response".equals(key)){
                    tmpFacts.remove(key);
                }
           }

        System.out.println("PreScreeningEngineVo: "+AvengersJSonConverter.convertToJSON(tmpFacts));
        System.out.println("****************************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("PostScreeningEngineVo: "+AvengersJSonConverter.convertToJSON(facts));

        return facts;
    }
}
```

Comment: You neither need a loop or that if for that, just call `tmpFacts.remove("response")` and to delete more, create a separate method with a varargs `private void removeFromMap(Map<....> map, String... keysToRemove)` and call it like `removeFromMap("response", "blub", "test");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list of elements to remove and the contains method.

So this:

```
   if("response".equals(key))
```

Would change to:

```
if(removables.contains(key))
```

But, you'd have to declare `removables` somewhere, like this:

```
private List<String> removables = new ArrayList("response", "HULC");
```

Comment: So you prefer to iterate the list for each key (which is O(n)) instead if just calling `tmpFacts.remove(..)` for each item of that list, which would be O(1)? ... ok.

Comment: It depends. Given the loop I assumed that you'd want to add or remove things from the removable list dynamically. If it is a static list, and my code here creates a static list, then yeah you'd remove the loop and just have the remove statements, as you said in your comment to the question.